# AWS route53 to GCP load balancing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-route53, gcp-load-balancer

I have a DNS record created in AWS. For example let's say xyz.com. I have a service running in gcp exposed through a load balancer. Now I want to use aws dns to route traffic to GCP LB. SO I created an alias record in AWS as "demo.xyz.com" and pointed to the ip of gcp load balancer. Still it does not work. Am i missing anything here. Need your help.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a Route 53 ALIAS record. Use an A resource record specifying the IP address of the Google HTTP(S) Load Balancer.